# TwoWayView запаздывает отрисовка

Tags: android, listview

Всем здравствуйте.
Для горизонтального  списка использую следующию [вьюху](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view).

При старте она подготавливается  вот так:

```
    void initSelector(DateTime time, int countDays) {
    DateTime selectorDate = time;
    ArrayList<String> list_days = new ArrayList<>();

    if (countDays == 7) {

        list_days.add("Пн\n" + selectorDate.withDayOfWeek(1).getDayOfMonth());
        list_days.add("Вт\n" + selectorDate.withDayOfWeek(2).getDayOfMonth());
        list_days.add("Ср\n" + selectorDate.withDayOfWeek(3).getDayOfMonth());
        list_days.add("Чт\n" + selectorDate.withDayOfWeek(4).getDayOfMonth());
        list_days.add("Пт\n" + selectorDate.withDayOfWeek(5).getDayOfMonth());
        list_days.add("Суб\n" + selectorDate.withDayOfWeek(6).getDayOfMonth());
        list_days.add("Вс\n" + selectorDate.withDayOfWeek(7).getDayOfMonth());

        selectorAdapter = new SelectorAdapter(getActivity(), list_days, new DateTime().getDayOfWeek() - 1);

        lvTest.setAdapter(selectorAdapter);
        selectorAdapter.setCallback(new CallbackOnClick() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(Object param) {
                // Logi.d("param = " + param);
                selectorAdapter.setSelection((int) param);
                guide_list.setSelectedGroup((int) param);
                test_booelan = false;
            }
        });
        //  selectorAdapter.setSelection(new DateTime().getDayOfWeek() - 1);
    } else {
        //lvTest.scrollTo(0,0);

        String day_name = "";
        int selection = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < countDays; i++) {
            switch (selectorDate.getDayOfWeek() - 1) {
                case 0:
                    day_name = "Пн\n";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    day_name = "Вт\n";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    day_name = "Ср\n";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    day_name = "Чт\n";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    day_name = "Пт\n";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    day_name = "Суб\n";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    day_name = "Вс\n";
                    break;
            }

            list_days.add(day_name + "" + selectorDate.getDayOfMonth());
            if (selectorDate.getDayOfMonth() == new DateTime().getDayOfMonth()) {
                //selection = i;
                selection = selectorDate.getDayOfWeek() - 1;
                //Logi.d("selection sadas=" + selection);
            }

            selectorDate = selectorDate.plusDays(1);

        }

        selectorAdapter = new SelectorAdapter(getActivity(), list_days, selection + 7);
        //selectorAdapter.setSelection(selection+6);
        selectorAdapter.setSelection(selection + 7);
        lvTest.setAdapter(selectorAdapter);
        selectorAdapter.setCallback(new CallbackOnClick() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(Object param) {
                selectorAdapter.setSelection((int) param);
                guide_list.setSelectedGroup((int) param);
                test_booelan = false;
            }
        });
        Logi.d("selection = "+selection);

        lvTest.setSelection(selection + 7);
        lvTest.refreshDrawableState();
        lvTest.invalidate();
        lvTest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lvTest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

/*
        selectorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lvTest.refreshDrawableState();
        lvTest.invalidate();*/
    }


}
```

*SelectorAdapter* кастомное расширение обыкновенного BaseAdapter'а.
Проблема следующая, когда список загружается на 14 позиций, выбранным оказывается  последний элемент(он подсвечивается в случае выбора), как только я попробую поскролить список, он сразу же отрисовывает выбор на верной позиции в списке. По логам смотрел айдишник итема передается нормальный, если нужно смогу скинуть код адаптера. Кто знает в чем проблема и как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка была в адапетер. Нужный для выбора пункт списка я выбирал по совпадению позиций списка-источника и строки списка-вьюхи.
Переписал метод  где определяю нужный для выбора пункт списка следующим образом:

```
   void initSelector(DateTime time, int countDays) {
    DateTime selectorDate = time;
    ArrayList<String> list_days = new ArrayList<>();

    if (countDays == 7) {

        list_days.add("Пн\n" + selectorDate.withDayOfWeek(1).getDayOfMonth());
        list_days.add("Вт\n" + selectorDate.withDayOfWeek(2).getDayOfMonth());
        list_days.add("Ср\n" + selectorDate.withDayOfWeek(3).getDayOfMonth());
        list_days.add("Чт\n" + selectorDate.withDayOfWeek(4).getDayOfMonth());
        list_days.add("Пт\n" + selectorDate.withDayOfWeek(5).getDayOfMonth());
        list_days.add("Суб\n" + selectorDate.withDayOfWeek(6).getDayOfMonth());
        list_days.add("Вс\n" + selectorDate.withDayOfWeek(7).getDayOfMonth());

        selectorAdapter = new SelectorAdapter(getActivity(), list_days, new DateTime().getDayOfWeek() - 1);

        lvTest.setAdapter(selectorAdapter);
        selectorAdapter.setCallback(new CallbackOnClick() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(Object param) {
                // Logi.d("param = " + param);
                selectorAdapter.setSelection((int) param);
                guide_list.setSelectedGroup((int) param);
                test_booelan = false;
            }
        });
        //  selectorAdapter.setSelection(new DateTime().getDayOfWeek() - 1);
    } else {
        //lvTest.scrollTo(0,0);
        String cur_name="";
        String day_name = "";
        int selection = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < countDays; i++) {
            switch (selectorDate.getDayOfWeek() - 1) {
                case 0:
                    day_name = "Пн\n";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    day_name = "Вт\n";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    day_name = "Ср\n";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    day_name = "Чт\n";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    day_name = "Пт\n";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    day_name = "Суб\n";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    day_name = "Вс\n";
                    break;
            }

            list_days.add(day_name + "" + selectorDate.getDayOfMonth());
            if (selectorDate.getDayOfMonth() == new DateTime().getDayOfMonth()) {
                //selection = i;
                selection = selectorDate.getDayOfWeek() - 1;
                cur_name = day_name + "" + selectorDate.getDayOfMonth();
                //Logi.d("selection sadas=" + selection);
            }

            selectorDate = selectorDate.plusDays(1);

        }

        selectorAdapter = new SelectorAdapter(getActivity(), list_days, selection + 7);
        //selectorAdapter.setSelection(selection+6);
        selectorAdapter.setSelection(selection + 7);
        selectorAdapter.setTextSelectDay(cur_name);
        lvTest.setAdapter(selectorAdapter);
        selectorAdapter.setCallback(new CallbackOnClick() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(Object param) {
                selectorAdapter.setSelection((int) param);
                guide_list.setSelectedGroup((int) param);
                test_booelan = false;
            }
        });
        Logi.d("selection = "+selection);

        lvTest.setSelection(selection + 7);
        selectorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

/*
        selectorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lvTest.refreshDrawableState();
        lvTest.invalidate();*/
    }


}
```

А в адаптер добавил переменную строку и переписал метод *getView*:

```
  String textSelectDay="";

public String getTextSelectDay() {
    return textSelectDay;
}

public void setTextSelectDay(String textSelectDay) {
    this.textSelectDay = textSelectDay;
}
```

....

```
    int innerPosotion=0;
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     innerPosotion = position;
    Logi.d("position = "+position);

    View retval = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.selector_item_layout, null);


    TextView title = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.title);
    RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout)retval.findViewById(R.id.container_inner);

    container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            callback.onClick(innerPosotion);
        }
    });

    title.setText((String)getItem(position));

    if(textSelectDay.equals(list.get(position))){//selection == position
        container.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.oval);
        title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }/* else {
        container.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }*/

    if (retval != null) {
        Logi.d("retval!= null");
        return retval;
    }  else {
        Logi.d("reval == null");
        return new ViewGroup(mContext) {
            @Override
            protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {

            }
        };
    }
}
```